# Paged queries with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I'm currently working on a migration project, to migrate data from the old db to the new one (please do not ask why I'm going through a Java application for this, it's what the customer requires).

There was some, initial, code which I'm updating now. One of the things I'm changing is using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` rather then the boiler-plate code which was there.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way yet to execute paged queries on a `JdbcTemplate`, analogue to the old code:

```
Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
statement.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
statement.setFetchSize(1000);
return statement.executeQuery();
```

The `getConnection()` just return a `Connection` object, created in plain JDBC code (it's not part of a `SessionFactory` or a framework implementation).

I would then loop over the resultset, mapping the rows one at a time. Does anyone know if there's an easy way to achieve the same functionality with `JdbcTemplate`?

TIA

Comment: *please do not ask why I'm going through a Java application for this, it's what the customer requires*. It's also a good idea.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Basically: I had Spring Batch in mind. A lot of what it does: chunk processing, transaction management, restartability etc. would not be possible with just SQL.

Comment: Ah of course, regarding your answer that's a logical statement :). Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the natural choice for such an Application is [Spring Batch](https://web.archive.org/web/20100703074945/http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) (read the impressive [Features page](https://web.archive.org/web/20101130113812/http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/features.html))

Here are the sections that should be relevant to you:

**[ItemReaders and ItemWriters > DataBase](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#database)**
and in particular [`JdbcPagingItemReader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#JdbcPagingItemReader)

Comment: It can do the job and a lot more, but it's also darn complicated. I'm currently struggling with it myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean sth. like this?

```
SimpleJdbcTemplate template = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

List<String> result = template.query("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id > ?",
    new RowMapper<String>() {

        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getString("name");
        }

    }, 666
);
```

Or this:

```
template.getJdbcOperations().query("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id > ?",
        new Object[] { 666 },
        new RowCallbackHandler() {

            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                System.out.println(String.format(
                    "Got '%s'", rs.getString("name")));
            }

        }
);
```

Comment: Not exactly, this will return and map all records with id larger then 666. I need a solution which would return one record at a time and map it. Thanks for your response!